# Storing Variables Across Multiple Pages With localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an engineering simulator, and I want to be able to have multiple things you can choose from. On the first page, I have radio buttons:

```html
<div id="radiobuttons" class="container" name="buttons" align=center>

  <h2>I Want my Building to be Made of:</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="brick-option" name="material" value="1" onClick="choose('Bricks')">
      <label for="brick-option">Bricks</label>

      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="wood-option" name="material" value="3" onClick="choose('Wood')">
      <label for="wood-option">Wood</label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="stone-option" name="material" value="2" onClick="choose('Stone')">
      <label for="stone-option">Stone</label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, on the second page, I want to have a slider:

```html
  <main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
      <h2>
        Choose the Height of Your Building
      </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" onchange="rangeValue=this.value;my2Function()">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>
```

I want both pages to affect the same variable, `chanceofdeath`. I would think that you use `localStorage`, but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to do it. Can you give me a few lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store value of `chanceofdeath` variable like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("chanceofdeath", chanceofdeath);
```

Then you can get value like this:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem("chanceofdeath");
```

Here is a little example:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BDxUL/23/)

To see `localStorage` content please follow these steps:

1. Simply open the Developer Tools by pressing `F12`.

2)Click on the `Application`  tab and you will see `localStorage's` content.

Comment: How would I add that into my radio button and slider code?

Comment: So, When you click radio button you have to use `localStorage.setItem("chanceofdeath", chanceofdeath);` .Or, when you want to get value use `var value=localStorage.getItem("chanceofdeath");`

Comment: If you give me more details, I can help you.

Comment: Should I use session storage or local storage, because I want multiple people to be able to try my program

Comment: All people will have own `localStorage` on their browser.

Comment: Please take a look now :https://jsfiddle.net/kzyffz9v/2/ and https://jsfiddle.net/rhwbqxb3/1/